# How to use bool in C#

Tags: c#, boolean

I am completely new to C# and I know this is an extremely basic question but after searching I couln't find any answers here or elsewhere on the internet.  When using bool in C#, you can have parameters, and then something inside your curly brackets.  I'm curious as to what parameters a boolean can have?  Everywhere I look it seems that they are always either just true or false and never take parameters.  For instance:

```
public bool TestBool(double number)
{
...some code...
}
```

Where I typed "some code", when would this code get used?  Is it called every time the boolean evaluates to true?  If anyone has any knowledge or advice on somewhere to read up on this I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: It is irrelevant that it is a boolean, it is just the return type of that method. It is not like JavaScript's `function` keyword, you do not _need_ to use `bool` to declare a method/function. May I suggest reading a bit more? Start at [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: The bool you are talking about is the return type of the method. Suggest some reading. Consider http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm or thousands of other resources found online.

Comment: A `Boolean` is just a type that is used to express two states; it can either have `true` or `false` as it´s value...

Comment: This is method. you need to learn about methods first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TestBool` is the name of the method.

The `bool` portion is the return type. - it returns either true or false depending on the logic in the method.

`public` means that anything that references this dll can call the method `TestBool`.

the `(double number)` portion means that the method `TestBool` accepts a parameter of type double, which can be used within the method.

Answer (score 5):

`bool`is a basic true/false type that cannot take parameters. In your example, you have a function (method) that does something with a number and returns true or false (the `bool`) depending on the result. So it might for example be:

```
public bool TestBool(double number)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However you never really need to work with `true` and `false` directly as any expression like `number > 0` returns a `bool` itself, so your function can just be:

```
public bool TestBool(double number)
{
    return number > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bool` is the *return type* of the method `TestBool`, and `number` is the only *parameter*. This means that any code that uses your function `TestBool` has to *give* it a `double`, and *gets* a `bool` in return.

The return type goes before the method name, and parameters go inside the parentheses after the method name.

The code inside the method can use the value of `number` for any calculations it needs, but must at some point return a `bool` value (`true` or `false`).